# What is this Perforce action?

Tags: perforce, unreal-engine4

[image]

I'm wondering what actions results in the left part of the graph, i.e. the red dashed arrow? This was done by Unreal Engine's Perforce plugin, when I renamed this file and submitted this change. The action shows **add** if I highlight that revision, but according to legend, this is a **merge w/ edit** action, so it doesn't seem to match.

The right part is my test, using P4V's **move/rename** action, and the action shows **move/rename**, which matches the legend **Add (branch w/ edit)**, so this one seems fine.

So, what exactly happened in the left part? Is it really a merge w/ edit? Is it a correct result if someone is doing rename? Is move/add the only correct result when doing rename?

Thanks.

Comment: The compound actions (branch with edit, merge with edit, etc.) are informing you that you included changes from one file into another file, but also **altered** those changes as you did so. For example, when changing a Java file's package, it is common to rename the file to its new source directory, but also change the 'package a.b.c;' statement in the the contents of the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mind-twister but there isn't necessarily a mismatch.

First the actions: the first is an **add** because the new file is created *in addition* to the old one. In contrast, the second is a **move/add** because you're adding a file by *moving* it from the old location, hence the old one ceases to exist. Indeed, you start the whole exercise with one file, and end it with two (rather than with three, as you would if you performed two adds; or rather than with one, as you would if you perform two move/adds).

Now the arrows. You're right the naming seems completely out of touch with the naming of the actions. I have no idea why there's the inconsistency.

You're asking about the **Merge w/ Edit** specifically. Perforce has four similar but distinct actions that could have been used here: `p4 integrate`, `p4 merge`, `p4 copy`, and `p4 populate`. There are subtle differences that don't matter here. At any case, all these actions do "merge" the file so I think the naming is OK. Intuitively, I feel this could/should have been done by `p4 copy` (since the target didn't exist, so you didn't have to merge anything) but it's also perfectly possible that Unreal Engine decided to use `p4 merge` or `p4 integrate` anyway. That, I believe, explains why the arrow is a **Merge**. As for the **w/ Edit**, did you perhaps make a (textual) edit in the file while duplicating it?

Comment: Unreal Engine uses a technique called "Redirector" for the sake of renaming their assets. "Redirector" requires the original asset to be stayed in the original place, maybe that's the reason why they are using a command that results in a Merge w/ Edit rather than Add (branch w/ edit), since they indeed need 2 files in the end. In this test I'm not doing any edit with the file, just renaming, I think Perforce maybe uses a universal legend no matter there's edit or not. The 4 commands you provided are exactly what I was asking! Thanks for your great answer!